# How to be sure the JS websocket's onMessage() even handler finished running before handling a new message

Tags: javascript, websocket, event-handling

I have a single page application that is driven by messages I receive through a websocket. For each message I receive the onMessage() handler starts and sets some variables for Vue.js and the page is updated. My problem is that I need to be sure that the onMessage() javascript event handler attached to my websocket in the page has finished running before it starts again with another message that could be arrived in the meantime.
At the moment, the onMessage() handler sometimes starts running before the already running onMessage() handler has finished working, because the onMessage() handler could take quite some time to finish its work and a new message could arrive in this time.
I need to avoid that... Question is: what is the better approach? Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. A subsequent event *cannot* interrupt the previous event handler. Now, you posted no code, so it's possible that your event handler is starting an asynchronous process. That could allow a new message-handling event to get through.

Comment: Exactly. I set some Vue.js variables and that starts the Vue.js rendering work that I suspect is asynchronous. I could try to post a small portion of significant code of my project, I did not post it because it is very long. Conceptually, though, the problem is the one you pointed out. Is there any approach to avoid that?

Comment: @Pointy Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: Well you could have the message handler stash messages in a queue or something like that, so that an in-progress handler can find them just before it finishes, but basically you're on your own.

Comment: @Wendelin because it is not an "answer".  Without seeing code, it's impossible to say anything definitive.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to post some code. Thank you!